# Web-restricted user keeps trying to be the one to make web requests

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, administrator

I have an admin account on my machine that I use for installing software, but it is restricted in other aspects such as going to the web.  It is not an account with which I regularly log into the computer.  Normally it is just used for "Run as other user..." options in Windows.  The normal account I login with has little to no admin privileges but has full access to the web.

However, since implementing this change, I find that no matter what else I have been doing on the computer, if I run a program or script using the admin account, suddenly all my web requests try to use that user (and thus are blocked).  In other words, I'm still logged in as the non-admin user, but when I try to navigate to any site it is blocked.  The only way I've found to undo this (short of rebooting) is to lock my machine and unlock it with the password.

Any ideas as to why this account keeps commandeering the web requests?  It happens with any browser I have open and seems to happen no matter what I do with the admin account (basically any time I enter the admin password).  It also happens to non-browser related internet (program updates, remote connections, etc.). Is there any way to keep this from happening automatically when I use the admin account?